# Apache Camel - How is the method name selected for invocation in this bean?

Tags: java, apache-camel, javabeans

I am just starting out with Apache Camel and I am confused as to how Camel is selecting which method to invoke in the following code:
[image]

This a part of this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/91UiQgazt3g?t=1859).

someBean is defined as :

```
@Singleton
public class SomeBean {
    private int counter;
    public String someMethod(String body); //Not providing the full definition as it is in the video.
}
```

According to the [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html#BeanBinding-Choosingthemethodtoinvoke) these rules are used to select a method for invocation, but I am unable to make out which rule is used.

How can Camel figure out which method to call just by the bean object ?

Answer (score 0):

The described [method selection mechanism in the Camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html#BeanBinding-Choosingthemethodtoinvoke) you mention is **just the "top of the iceberg"**. There are even more ways to choose a method of a Bean.

If you want to learn the **full blown Bean method selection mechanism**, get a copy of [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition) by Claus Ibsen. Chapter 4.4 is dedicated to this subject and explains it on almost 10 pages with examples.

In your case I guess the matching rule is

> Is there **only one method with a single parameter**?

If this is the case, Camel will use this method. You can try this very easily with a [RouteTest](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html). Create a route and a simple bean as in the video. When it works, start to add methods to the bean and look what method is chosen.